# How to cancel done() in a SwingWorker thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, action, swingworker

I am making a program which should be able to stop the whole process on the click of a button.

I have used `sw.cancel(true);` to do so, however, the `SwingWorker` method `protected void done()` is still operating.

How can I on a push of a button cancel the whole thing? Not just the `doInBackground()` method?

Here's the whole relevant code below for those who are interested:

```
sw = new SwingWorker() {
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //Pravljenje timera
        t = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });

        //Provera stanja checkboxova
        if(jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
            try {
                int delay =(int) jSpinner2.getValue();
                jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
                Thread.sleep(delay*60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(App_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
            jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);   

            Date delay2 = (Date) jSpinner1.getValue();
            userCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("delay2: " + delay2);
            userCal.setTime(delay2);
            System.out.println("userCal:" + userCal);
            Calendar sysCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("sysCal: " + sysCal);
            timerAtDate = 
                (((int) userCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - (int) sysCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                ((int) userCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - (int) sysCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) * 60 * 1000 +
                ((int) userCal.get(Calendar.SECOND) - (int) sysCal.get(Calendar.SECOND)) * 1000);
            Thread.sleep(timerAtDate);
        }

        return null; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("Done!");

        t.start();
        t.setRepeats(false);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setLocation(700, 300);
        dialog.setSize(600, 400);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(jSlider1.getValue());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Zapravo gotov");
        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(jLabel2.getBackground());
        dialog.setModal(true);
        Assignment_Tajmer_Aplikacija.f.setVisible(false); 
    }
};

sw.execute();

private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling cosadde here:
    jSlider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            //System.out.println(source.getValue());
        }
    });
}                                     

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JColorChooser jcc = new JColorChooser();
    Color c = jcc.showDialog(null, "Choose background color", Color.yellow);
    jLabel2.setForeground(c);
    jLabel2.setBackground(c);
    jLabel2.setText("Color: " + c.getRGB() + "(RGB)");
}                                        

private void jCheckBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
}                                          

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    sw.cancel(true);
}                                        

private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: `SwingWorker` is generally used for time consuming processing in the background so it doesn't freeze the UI. It also allows you to send updates to the UI so you can for example update a progress bar. In your case I cannot see anything like this which makes me wonder why you are using `SwingWorker` at all?

Comment: There is more to the code, I am using a SwingWorker because the timer can be set 10 years in the future, I have never set the maximum, I don't want the program to freeze for 10 years :P
And also to make it easier to press the "stop" button which cancels the timer and allows the user to access the other buttons once again (Since when they click start, all other buttons except "stop" are unclickable)~

Comment: Your implementation of `doInBackground()` is incorrectly synchronized; manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Please update your question to explain the [*actual problem*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/163188).

Comment: This can be a very time consuming process, which can take up to 10 years of waiting, therefore I used a SwingWorker so that the program doesn't freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `isCancelled()` method in the beginning of `done()` to see if you should do the operations or not.

Comment: Wait, so at the beginning of the done() method I type sw.isCancelled(), and what afterwards? It should return the state of the SwingWorker, how can I use the returned value to stop the done() method of progressing with the code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, as you might guess `isCancelled()` returns a boolean. It would go very well together with an `if` statement.

Comment: So, if it returns "true" i go ahead and write:
if (sw.isCancelled == true) {
//Stop the method
}
But what should I write instead of the comment to actually stop the method?

Comment: You decided to skip the basics and went straight to Swing, didn't you? I'd advise you to learn how to use the `if` clause before continuing to program.

Comment: No, not really...
I'm guessing I'm making a really stupid and basic mistake, but I am new to Swing and it's the hardest part of my studies up until now :(

Comment: But are you new to `if` or `return`?

Comment: No, I also have two if clauses in this very code, and have worked with it in the past, I am generally new to programming and do it in my spare time :')

Comment: What about `return`?

Comment: Didn't really have too much experience with return, however, I used it a few times before in simple apps...

Comment: So I'm dropping clues like I have a hole in my pocket, but you don't seem to be catching on. As the name indicates `return` returns from a method. If the method is not void, it is used to return a value, in a void method it just returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel it but you can short-circuit it so that it finishes early.  Use some shared state flag between your threads to signal.

Comment: So I make a method called in doInBackground()? And that method stops the done() method? But what should I write in the method? That was the question up there :D